# Python groupby: strange behavior

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-itertools

I've come across this strange thing about `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

source_data = ((1, 10), (1, 20), (1, 30), (1, 40), (2, 20))

d1 = {k: [x for x in v] for k, v in groupby(source_data, itemgetter(0))}

d2 = {k: v for k, v in groupby(source_data, itemgetter(0))}
d2 = {k: [x for x in v] for k, v in d2.items()}

print(d1)
print(d2)
```

As an output I get:

```
{1: [(1, 10), (1, 20), (1, 30), (1, 40)], 2: [(2, 20)]}
{1: [], 2: [(2, 20)]}
```

Why are these two resulting dicts different?

Is it some bug in Python library, or am I using it wrong way?

I am using Python 3.5

Comment: You are using it the wrong way, I'm afraid, see the dupe.